# css gradient background for text

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

I'm trying to achieve this effect with css:

[image]

So, I have this markup:

```css
h2 {
    color:red;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+1,000000+100&1+44,0+100 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 1%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 44%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 44%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 44%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */}
```

```html
<h2>Cool is for people who don't accept themselves</h2>
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: There is no *gradient* there in the image :D Anyway have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719354/html-table-cell-partial-background-fill/37719500#37719500) to see how to achieve partial background fills. That is all that you need to re-create that image (just a `linear-gradient(black,black)` with `background-size: 50% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient(to right, black 60%, white 60%)`

```css
div {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 60%, white 60%);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda, at.</div>
```

Or you can use two pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 300px;
}
div:before, div:after {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: -1;
}
div:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda, at.</div>
```