# draw a bar in a td cell

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-easyui

I have the following simple code

```
  <tr>                           
        <td>20 Apr 1987, 06:00-07:00</td>            
        <td> <input type=text id=rainfall1 value="28.95">mm</input> </td>
    </tr>                          
    <tr>                           
         <td>20 Apr 1987, 07:00-08:00</td>  
          <td> <input type=text id=rainfall2 value="38.87">mm</input> </td> 
    </tr>                          
    <tr>                           
         <td>20 Apr 1987, 08:00-09:00</td>       
          <td> <input type=text id=rainfall3 value="14.89">mm</input> </td>
    </tr>
```

which produces 
[this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2aG2.jpg).
I want to add a third

```
<td> ... here draw a bar ...  </td>
```

cell which draws a bar that corresponds to the values of rainfall and which updates automatically when the values in the input change. What would be the easiest way to do this? Code snippets are highly appreciated. The input elements are part of a bigger form.

Comment: What's a "bar" exactly?

Comment: Also, you can't wrap the "mm" using an input like that. `textarea` you can. It should just be `<input type="text" id="id" value="some value" />`

Comment: See the answer here :
[HTML TABLE CELL PARTIAL BACKGROUND FILL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719354/html-table-cell-partial-background-fill)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a `div` inside of your `td` with some CSS styling. For example, use this:

```
.bar{
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Then make the HTML like this:

```
<table id=table>
    <tr>                           
        <td>20 Apr 1987, 08:00-09:00</td>       
        <td> <input type=text id=rainfall0 value="14.89">mm</input> </td>
        <td><div class="bar" id="bar0"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now use this JavaScript to make the height of the bar relative tot the value of the input:

```
var amnt = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
for(i = 0; i < amnt; i++){
    var element = document.getElementById("rainfall" + i);
    rainfall = element.value;
    var el = document.getElementById("bar" + i);
    el.style.width = rainfall;
}
```

This should work, have not tested it yet, will do so now.

Comment: The javascript code should be placed in a function? And then when will be that function called? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: Also you have to define somehow the css class named "bar"?

Comment: When do you want the bar to be drawn? Is it an input for the user or is it just a static value? If this is the case you can simply put it in a window.onload = function(){code here};

Answer (score 0):

you can use jqueryUI for this matter. try to download these required [jqueryUI files](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.4&components=1100000000000001000001111111111111111&zThemeParams=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) and follow the code below:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>progress bar in table example</title>
        <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
        body{
            font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
            margin: 50px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>progress bar in table example</h1>
        <table>
      <tr>                           
            <td>20 Apr 1987, 06:00-07:00</td>            
            <td> <input type=text id=rainfall1 value="28.95">mm</input> </td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>                          
        <tr>                           
             <td>20 Apr 1987, 07:00-08:00</td>  
              <td> <input type=text id=rainfall2 value="38.87">mm</input> </td> 
    <td></td>
        </tr>                          
        <tr>                           
             <td>20 Apr 1987, 08:00-09:00</td>       
             <td> <input type=text id=rainfall3 value="14.89">mm</input> </td>
<!--here is the progress bar div element-->
             <td><div id="progressbar" style="width:200px"></div></td>
        </tr>  
    </table>
    <button id="plusBtn">+10</button>
    <button id="minusBtn">-10</button>
    <label id="progressLabel">label</label>
    <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    var progressVal = 20;
    //these minus and plus functions are just for an interactive progress bar example. 
    //you don't have to use them
    $("#plusBtn").click(function(){
        progressVal += 10;
        $("#progressLabel").html(progressVal.toString());
        console.log(progressVal);
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: progressVal
    });

    });
        $("#minusBtn").click(function(){
        progressVal -= 10;
        $("#progressLabel").html(progressVal.toString());
            console.log(progressVal);
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: progressVal
    });

    //the progressbar() function updates the bar's value
    });
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: progressVal
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```